# How to update a part of data in a json file using python

Tags: python, json

I want to update only a part of data in this json file and im struggling to do it.

the json file is as follows:

```json
[
    {
        "IP": "Not Specified",
        "MOTD": "Not Specified",
        "Seed": "Not Specified",
        "Server_image": "Not Specified",
        "Cracked_status": "Not Specified",
        "Version": "Not Specified",
        "Software": "Not Specified",
        "Difficulty": "Not Specified"
    }
]
```

I want to update the `IP` value using `python`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried this but it feels too complicated

Comment: ```for x in dataa:
    for y in x:
        if y == 'value':
         var_u_writing_back =  x.update({y: "value3"})```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple. You can try this solution. I hope it will work for you.

```
list_name[0]["IP"] = "here will be the update value"
```

Answer (score 0):

the easy way to convert to dict modify and convert to JSON

```
import json


json_t = '[{"IP":"Not Specified","MOTD":"Not Specified","Seed":"Not Specified","Server_image":"Not Specified","Cracked_status":"Not Specified","Version":"Not Specified","Software":"Not Specified","Difficulty":"Not Specified"}]'
list_t = json.loads(json_t)
# modify the dict
json_t = json.dumps(list_t)
```